# Query in Laravel, get multiple data with GroupBy

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with these columns:

```
prime (date)
data (json)
account char()
```

I'm trying to get all three fields from my query and groupBy by "account" field.

The problem is doing this query:

```
DB::connection('aa')-table('bb')
->where('prime', ">", $date)
->select('prime', 'data', 'account')
->groupBy('account')
```

The query fails without returning anything.

Ideally I'd like to be able to get all records by account and then have the other data in the array so I can loop through the results.

Comment: If you want every row, then you may want `orderBy` instead of `groupBy`. Order will sort every row, group will combine the rows based on unique player_account values.

Comment: Your query doesn't return anything because you haven't done a `get()` at the end, I suspect.

Comment: @aynber but that's the thing I need the data combined. I want all same account records grouped by ids.

Comment: what you have at the moment is a Builder instance, you need to chain a final ->get(). i assume the missing > before table is a typo.

Comment: When you have more when one record for player_account what event_time and event_data should be presented?

Comment: Also please provide MySQL version

Comment: Yes if I have multiple records it should show. Right now, if I add a ->get() its empty. I am using Laravel 8.2.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` groups rows that have the same values into summary rows, so you cannot return all rows when using group by. Instead, since we want all data, we need to pull all the data and than if you want you can perform grouping via some function in php. In this case the grouping is performed in memory, not in the DB layer.

```php
DB::connection('aa')->table('bb')
  ->where('event_time', ">", $date)
  ->select('event_time', 'event_data', 'player_account')
  ->get() // pull all the data
  ->groupBy('player_account'); // use groupBy method provided by Laravel's collections
```

for more information on the `groupBy` method you can check https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-groupby

Comment: @user875139 if this was useful you can mark it as the answe

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing may be related to the way you are using the groupBy clause. When using groupBy you should include all the selected columns that are not part of an aggregate function. In your case you are selecting event_time, event_data, and player_account, but you are grouping only by player_account. You can try this below.

```
$results = DB::connection('aa')
->table('bb')
->where('event_time', '>', $date)
->select('player_account', DB::raw('MAX(event_time) as event_time'), 'event_data')
->groupBy('player_account')
->get();
```